# VB.Net: Parsing an XML Document

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, xml-namespaces, descendant

Code:

```
 Dim xmlString As String = File.ReadAllText(filepath)
 xmlString = fixTextForXML(xmlString)
 Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
 Dim namespaces As New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable)
 Dim myNameSpaces As New Dictionary(Of String, XNamespace)
 For Each myName As XAttribute In doc.Root.Attributes()
       Console.WriteLine(myName.ToString)
       If (myName.Name = "xmlns") Then
                namespaces.AddNamespace("ns", doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace.ToString)
                Dim tempNS As XNamespace = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace.ToString
                myNameSpaces.Add("ns", tempNS)
            Else
                Dim tempNS As XNamespace = myName.Value
                myNameSpaces.Add(myName.Name.LocalName, tempNS)
                namespaces.AddNamespace(myName.Name.LocalName, myName.Value)
            End If
        Next
```

This allows me to use...

`Console.WriteLine(doc.Descendants.Elements(myNameSpaces("ns4") + "example").Value`

To grab the value of `example`. My issue here is there are multiple `example` in the xml...

```
<ns4:example>

<id>something</id>

<name>something</name>

</ns4:example>


<ns4:example>

<id>something</id>

<name>something</name>

</ns4:example>
```

How would I go about looping through and getting all of the `example's?

Answer (score 0):

The XDocument.Descendants.Elements returns an array of XElements so the following code would give you all the elements that meet your criteria

```
Dim list As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants.Elements(myNameSpaces("ns4") + "example").ToList()

For Each element As XElement In list
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value)
Next
```